# Setting file and folder permissions with Icacls

Tags: windows

Hi I manage a fairly large school and I want to use Icacls to set permissions on quite a number of our machines that are running XP service pack 3. I would like to set the administrative tools folder that is in the start menu so the studentscannot open the folder but only admins can. I am having problems with the syntax. I have seen a number of examples that use a switch that resets the inheritance but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Below is what I am using. Any help will be welcome. Thanks.

```
Icacls "c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Admistrative Tools" /inheritance:r /grant:r "Administrator":(OI)(CI)F
```

I am getting a invalid parameter error for "/inheritance:f" I have based the above on this article. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.geekofalltrades.aspx

Comment: That command works as written on Windows 7 (except for the typo in the file name) but it looks like the Windows XP version of `icacls.exe` doesn't support the `inheritance` flag: see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919240

Comment: Is it even available in windows xp? Are u using the 64 bit edition?